# Decimating a mesh subset

Tags: meshlab

In MeshLab, is there a way to do a lasso-type selection of a large OBJ terrain mesh and apply the quadratic edge collapse decimation only to that subset of the mesh?  I need to keep a small part of the mesh at a high density but decimate the rest to reduce model size.  If so, please let me know how to accomplish this.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can first select just the portion of mesh you want to simplify, and then check the "simplify only selected faces" in the quadric edge collapse decimation filter.